# 3D Vision doesn't work with dead island

Tags: dead-island, stereo-3d

I have a 3D Vision problem with Dead Island. See this video, at first 3d vision is deactivated, then activated via hotkey then deactivated again.

This is my Video.scr

```
Resolution(1280,720)
Monitor(0)
BPP(32)
PostProcess("Normal")
FSAA(1)
Fullscreen()
VSync() 
Shadows("High")
TexBPP(32)
TextureQuality("High")
Filtering("AnisotropicTrilinear")
Shadows("High")
ShadowMapSize(2048)
SpotShadowMapSize(2048)
GammaFloat(1.00)
MaxRefresh(60)
MaterialQuality(2)
FXFadeLevel(2)
WaterQuality(2)
GrassQuality(0)
EnvQuality("FullDynamic")
ShaderPath(3)
DisplayDeviceType(0,0.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000)
```

It used to work. Dead Island Version 1.3, GeForce GTX 570, Treiber 301.42.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just a hunch, but could it be the refresh lock?

Comment: what is a refresh lock?

Answer (score 2):

I "found" the "solution".

Update to 304.79 BETA drivers then it works again. It was just a driver issue.

Comment: +1 for coming back and posting your solution as a new user.